# How to extract part of url - dart/flutter

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to extract the part of url (To be more specific, I'm trying to extract the value of page_info parameter in the url which is next to rel="next"

```
String testUrl = "<https://demo.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=10&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJwcmV2IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDU4MDcyMTc1NCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBCcmFjZWxldCJ9>; rel='previous', <https://demo.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=10&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDIyNzcxMjA5MCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBIZWFydCBQZW5kYW50IE5lY2tsYWNlIn0>; rel='next'";

List<String> splitUrl = testUrl.split("=");
    print(splitUrl[5]);

// this is what it prints out
eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDIyNzcxMjA5MCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBIZWFydCBQZW5kYW50IE5lY2tsYWNlIn0>; rel

// this is what I'm trying to extract 

eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDIyNzcxMjA5MCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBIZWFydCBQZW5kYW50IE5lY2tsYWNlIn0 

// value for rel="next"
```

I tried to split the url by using split function on String but that would also bring the angle bracket with it. I'm trying to extract only page_info= parameter value which is for rel="next"

I know this has to do something with regex but I'm not really good at it! Any help would be really appreciated

I grabbed that url from header response (paginated REST API), it returns two page_info parameters (one for next and other one for previous page) I'm trying to extract value for next page. Splitting the url didn't help me

thank you

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help me! Anyway thank you for suggestion @PiyushPranjal

Comment: I grabbed that url from header response (paginated REST API), it returns two page_info parameters (one for next and other one for previous page) I'm trying to extract value for next page. Splitting the url didn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regEx pattern `page_info=([\w]+)`
gives you

eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJwcmV2IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDU4MDcyMTc1NCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBCcmFjZWxldCJ9

eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDIyNzcxMjA5MCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBIZWFydCBQZW5kYW50IE5lY2tsYWNlIn0

https://regexr.com/6qj1h

Comment: Thank you! Does Dart regex differs from JS regex because it didn't work (check the code, I updated the question)

Comment: Never mind! figured it out! Had to replace '\' with "\\"

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use [`Uri.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) to parse the URL:

```dart
void main() {
  String testUrl = "<https://demo.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=10&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJwcmV2IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDU4MDcyMTc1NCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBCcmFjZWxldCJ9>; rel='previous', <https://demo.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=10&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6NjczMDIyNzcxMjA5MCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjE4SyBHb2xkIFBsYXRlZCBIZWFydCBQZW5kYW50IE5lY2tsYWNlIn0>; rel='next'";

  // Extract just the URL.
  var match = RegExp(r'<([^>]*)>').firstMatch(testUrl);
  if (match != null) {
    var uri = Uri.parse(match.group(1)!);
    print(uri.queryParameters['page_info']); // Prints: eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJ...
  }
}
```

Note that the above wouldn't need any of the `RegExp` code if `testUrl` were a proper URL without the angle brackets and `rel='next'` junk.